# Minimum Vertex Cut

Tags: graph-theory

Assume that there is a graph with no special feature. This graph is partitioned into two sub graphs by removing some nodes and the edges connected to those nodes.

My aim is to find minimum number of these nodes which separates the graph into two components. However, I do not try to determine what these nodes are. I aims to find only its quantity.

How can I accomplish this ?

Comment: [Menger's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger%27s_theorem#Vertex_connectivity) for vertex connectivity seems to be what you want. I don't know any algorithm for this, but you could probably produce one with this, or with max-flow min-cut.

Comment: I analyzed the `Menger Theorem`. It almost answers my question, but the problem is that theorem does not provide global solution. It says that **the size of the minimum vertex cut for x and y (the minimum number of vertices whose removal disconnects x and y) is equal to the maximum number of pairwise vertex-independent paths from x to y.** In other words, the result depends on the pair of (x,y). If I choose another pair of vertices from the graph, the result alters.

Comment: I suppose you could take the minimum over all pairs $(x,y)$, which is totally inefficient, but will work. I can't help much more with this, but I found a [similar question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2877/minimum-cut-through-vertices-nodes-not-edges) on another SE site that should be useful to you.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/91370/755